# Load BigQuery table from local csv file

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have python script that insert json data into json file then from convert json to csv.

The problem I want to load BigQuery table from the local csv file relating to project file instead of Google Storage.

as it shown in the ref: [Load Csv data](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-storage-csv)

this's the python code

```
try:
    client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
    print("Table {} already exists.".format(table_id))
except NotFound:
    print("Table {} is not found.".format(table_id))
    
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
      autodetect=True,
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    # The source format defaults to CSV, so the line below is optional.
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
)


uri = "bigquery-demo/csv_data.csv"

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
    uri, table_id, job_config=job_config
)  # Make an API request.

load_job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

destination_table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print("Loaded {} rows.".format(destination_table.num_rows))
```

[image: googlecloud]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I understand what you would like to achieve by loading a constant csv file kept with the source code, but you might like to try [load table from file](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.load_table_from_file) function, which takes `A file handle opened in binary mode for reading.` as an input parameter. Just make sure that the file path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This doc explains how to import a local file
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-load-from-file

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()

# TODO(developer): Set table_id to the ID of the table to create.
# table_id = "your-project.your_dataset.your_table_name"

job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.CSV,
    skip_leading_rows=1,
    autodetect=True,
)

with open(file_path, "rb") as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)

job.result()  # Waits for the job to complete.

table = client.get_table(table_id)  # Make an API request.
print(
    "Loaded {} rows and {} columns to {}".format(
        table.num_rows, len(table.schema), table_id
    )
)
```